# Reset mouse cursor behavior after changing the default value in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

`I have a movie clip that I wanted to behave as a button on mouse over and mouse out, so I added a listener to change the cursor to button and arrow in roll over and roll out:

```
Object(this).my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,overButton);
Object(this).my_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,outButton);

function overButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Mouse.cursor="button";
}

function outButton(e:MouseEvent):void {
    Mouse.cursor="arrow";
}
```

The problem is that after moving the mouse over and out the `my_mc` and executing this code, the mouse cursor will always be arrow even when rolling over other button symbols. Is like it will only behave according to the last instruction which is the `outButton` function.

How can I reset the mouse cursor behavior so that it will work normally with selectable text areas and buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be restoring the `Mouse.cursor` property to "auto".

```
Mouse.cursor="auto"
```

Setting it to `MouseCursor="arrow"` on roll out means it will always show the arrow.

However, I would recommend removing these event listeners, and setting the [buttonMode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode) property of the `MovieClip` to `true`.

It's a bit cleaner, and I'm assuming performs better b/c Flash Player manages this without any extra code.

Comment: MouseCursor.AUTO gives me an error, is this AS3? I tried Mouse.cursor="auto" which didn't give an error but it didn't do the trick.